# Running NightmareJS with Mocha on server (Bamboo agent)

Tags: automated-tests, mocha.js, bamboo, nightmare

I have been battling this issue for some time now and can not seem to find a solution. When running tests with NightmareJS + mocha on the server they fail. I tried running with:

```
DEBUG=nightmare:* env ENV=staging mocha --harmony tests.js
```

But do not see any logs/actions errors etc. Just that tests are failing (timing out).

```
Error: timeout of 30000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

I am able to run only Mocha tests without NightmareJS, and they are working fine. Also when running nighmareJS tests on my local machine, they are working without any issues.

NightmareJS is installed on the server, package.json content:

```
"dependencies": {
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "mocha-generators": "^1.2.0",
    "mocha-bamboo-reporter": "*",
    "nightmare": "^2.2.0",
    "nodeunit" : "~0.8"
  }
```

Here is the code for the tests:

```
require('mocha-generators').install();
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var expect = require('chai').expect;

var url = null;
var options = {
    show: false,
    'webPreferences': {
        partition: 'something_xyz'
    }
};
if (process.env.ENV === 'staging') {
    console.log("Running tests against staging environment");
    url = 'https://staging.something.com/app/';

} else {
    console.log("Running tests against local environment");
    url = 'http://localhost:8080/app/';
}

describe('Nightmare JS tests', function() {
    this.timeout(30000);

    describe('base functionality', function() {
        var nightmare;
        before(function*() {
            nightmare = Nightmare(options);
        });

        after(function*() {
            var endTest = yield nightmare
                    .end()
        });

        it('Should be able to login', function*() {

            var result = yield nightmare
                    .goto(url)
                    .wait('img.google-login-btn')
                    .click('img.google-login-btn')
                    .wait('div.main-content.row h4')
                    .wait(1000)
                    .evaluate(function () {
                        return document.querySelector('div.main-content.row h4').innerText;

                    })

            expect(result).to.equal("Logged in!");

        });

        // here are the rest of the tests

    });
});
```

How can I debug this? As I am running on the server, I can not use show: true option.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you are running into general issues with /nightmare in a headless environment. See https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/224 for details. The easiest solution is to install Xvfb and run with `xvfb-run mocha ...`

You can also pass DEBUG flags for electron, such as `DEBUG=nightmare*,electron*` and get additional debugging output that may help in a situation like this, where Nightmare and Electron never successfully start up.

Comment: Running with xvfb-run mocha does not change anything. Still no errors, except timeout and no other errors. I will try debugging with electron parameters

Comment: Have you tried running just electron on your server, e.g. `electron --help`? You should have this in the dist/ directory of the `electron-prebuilt` package (dependency of nightmare). If you get no output from this then there's a problem with the server environment that causes electron to not work.

Answer (score 0):

It s an old issue but maybe it can help.
To run electron in an headless env you may need some stuff.

Look at this Dockerfile: https://github.com/aheuermann/docker-electron/blob/master/7/Dockerfile

It s the minimal libs you need.
And to start you script:

```
Xvfb -ac -screen scrn 1280x2000x24 :9.0 &
export DISPLAY=:9.0
DEBUG=* node src/index.js
```